# Raphael.js undefined variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I've recently turned to RaphaelJS, due to need of .onclick events on variables painted on a canvas. My problem is, I transformed my whole website to use raphaeljs, but, as I try to run it, it tells me that H (the variable I'm listening onclick to) is undefined.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rC2WP/)'s a jsfiddle of the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning `H.node.onclick` when the DOM is loaded, but `H` is not initialized until `drawbg` is called, which happens when you click on the canvas.

You can solve this problem by assigning the event handler after `drawbg` was called. You should also avoid global variables (such as `H`).

Answer (score 1):

You initiate the variable H in the function drawbg(), but you call methods to this variable before you've called this function.